# Error in Ajax code to get response from codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to send my request to CodeIgniter to get response from my database:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.confirm_send').on('click',function(){

var base = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';

var confirm_send_id=$(this).attr('id');


        $.ajax({
            'url': base + 'my_site/confirm_send',
            'type':'post',
            'dataType':'json',
            'data':{
                'id':confirm_send_id
            },
            'success':function(){
                alert("sucssess");},

            'error':function(){
                alert("Error");
            }


        });//end of ajax confirm send button

    });//end of confirm send button

    });//end of jquery
```

But I am getting an error.

Comment: The ajax error function can return three parameters. Investigate those a bit

Comment: on error occurs when a different state from 200 is getted

Comment: check `'url': base + 'my_site/confirm_send',`

Comment: Removed useless text. Instead, please share your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
 $('.confirm_send').on('click',function(){

     var base = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
     var confirm_send_id = $(this).attr('id');

     $.ajax({
        url: base + 'my_site/confirm_send',  //make sure it is a valid path
        type: 'POST',
        data:({'id':confirm_send_id}),
        success :  function(response){
             alert("Success");
        },

        error : function(response){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });//end of ajax confirm send button


});
```

Comment: thank you i should change datatype to text because i don't get any value from server and the error occurs for this type of data, now i get a little knowledge about json and data type

Answer (score 0):

It`s a server side coding issue that`s why it`s getting issue you can check error using response window it will display coding error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject PHP code into JavaScript. Remember that whatever script or css that you define will be run in the user's browser - and browsers don't interpret PHP code neither have direct access to your server.

You've gotta hard-code the base_url variable.
If you don't know it just `echo base_url();` on a page and copy it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.confirm_send').on('click',function(){

var base = 'http://yourproject_base_url'; //Set the full base url manually here. 

var confirm_send_id=$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        'url': base + 'my_site/confirm_send',
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'data':{
            'id':confirm_send_id
        },
        'success':function(){
            alert("sucssess");},

        'error':function(){
            alert("Error");
        }


    });//end of ajax confirm send button

});//end of confirm send button

});//end of jquery
```